# Add popover or info botton to accordionItem title panel in shiny

Tags: r, bootstrap-4, shiny, popover, bs4dash

I have a shiny app with `accordion` and I would like to add a popup message on the title panel either an info botton or a hovering function ! I have tried the `popover` from `bs4Dash` but it does not work on `accordionItem`  :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(bs4Dash)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      accordion(id = "accordion1",
        popover(       
        accordionItem(
        title = "Shiny Box",
        status = "success",
        solidHeader = TRUE,
        collapsed = TRUE,
         # bsPopover("Shiny Box","","test popover",
         #            "right", options = list(container = "body")),
        div(id="inline",  style="width:35vw;",
            div(HTML("<b>TEST </b>")),
            br(),
                   numericInputIcon("A", h5("test1"), value = 20, icon = icon("percent")) ,
                   numericInputIcon("B", h5("test2"), value = 40, icon = icon("percent")) ,
                   numericInputIcon("C", h5("test3"), value = 60, icon = icon("percent")) ,
                   numericInputIcon("D", h5("test4"), value = 20, icon = icon("percent")) ,
                   currencyInput("X", "Total", value = 0.3, format = "percentageUS2dec")
        )
      ),
      title = "My popover",
      placement = "right",
      content = "Test popover"
      )
    )
  )
),
  server = function(input, output) { }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to add a popover on the title panel would be to first add an `id` attribute to the title panel of the `accordionItem` using `tagAppendAttributes` and the CSS selector `.card-header`. Afterwards you could use `bs4Dash::addPopover` to add a popover to the title panel:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(bs4Dash)
library(shinyWidgets)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      accordion(
        id = "accordion1",
        accordionItem(
          title = "Shiny Box",
          status = "success",
          solidHeader = TRUE,
          collapsed = TRUE,
          div(
            id = "inline", style = "width:35vw;",
            div(HTML("<b>Hover anywhere to reveal the popover</b>")),
            br(),
            numericInputIcon("A", h5("test1"), value = 20, icon = icon("percent")),
            numericInputIcon("B", h5("test2"), value = 40, icon = icon("percent")),
            numericInputIcon("C", h5("test3"), value = 60, icon = icon("percent")),
            numericInputIcon("D", h5("test4"), value = 20, icon = icon("percent")),
            currencyInput("X", "Total", value = 0.3, format = "percentageUS2dec")
          )
        ) |> 
          tagAppendAttributes(id = "accordion_item", .cssSelector = ".card-header")
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    addPopover(
      id = "accordion_item",
      options = list(
        title = "Shiny Box",
        content = "Test Popover",
        trigger = "hover"
      )
    )
  }
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option where you use `addPopover` in the server function to attach a popover to a specific id.

**Edits**

I've included two use cases since it's not clear to me if you want the popover to display when the mouse is over the entire `accordionItem` or a specific id inside the accordionItem. So both options are shown below.

**Demo**
[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(bs4Dash)
library(shinyWidgets)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      accordion(id = "accordion1",
        accordionItem(
          title = "Shiny Box",
          status = "success",
          solidHeader = TRUE,
          collapsed = TRUE,
          div(id="inline",  style="width:35vw;",
            div(id = "pop-hover", HTML("<b>Hover over this to reveal the popover</b>")),
            br(),
            numericInputIcon("A", h5("test1"), value = 20, icon = icon("percent")),
            numericInputIcon("B", h5("test2"), value = 40, icon = icon("percent")),
            currencyInput("X", "Total", value = 0.3, format = "percentageUS2dec")
          )
        ),
        accordionItem(
          id = "item2",
          title = "Next",
          status = "danger",
          solidHeader = TRUE,
          collapsed = TRUE,
          div(
            HTML("<b>Hover anywhere in the accordionItem to reveal the popover</b>"),
            br(),
            numericInputIcon("C", h5("test3"), value = 60, icon = icon("percent")),
            numericInputIcon("D", h5("test4"), value = 20, icon = icon("percent")),  
          )
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    addPopover(
      id = "pop-hover",
      options = list(
        title = "Title Popover",
        placement = "left",
        content = "Test popover",
        trigger = "hover"
      )
    )
    addPopover(
      id = "item2",
      options = list(
        title = "Item Popover",
        placement = "right",
        content = "next popover",
        trigger = "hover"
      )
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, the problem is the `accordionItem` ! your solution does not work if I have more than one `accordionItem` . because they will be under one `accordion` with the same ID !

Comment: Look at my inline comment. - Add a unique id to the accordionItem then use that same Id in the addPopover function.  In the example above, change the id to ‘test’. It will work for just the accordionItem.

Comment: @user9112767 - please see my recent edits to show a popover on a specific `accordionItem` or even a popover on a component inside an accordionItem.